# Colour profile not matching - Adobe Illustrator, InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, color, creative-cloud

I am a bit confused as to why I am getting a prompt pop up when I am copying something from adobe InDesign and pasting to Illustrator and vice versa.

[image]

I have checked colour settings in both programmes and they look the same to me. Perhaps there is something else I should be checking?

Here are the settings in both InDesign and Illustrator

[image]

[image]

Comment: Relaunch the apps. If not the entire system. Could be read error or a corrupt profile. I've had this happen, and just relaunching the apps corrects it - especially if they've been running for several days or weeks.

Comment: The color settings are the defaults for new documents. The document you copy from or paste into could have other settings.